My daughter is 12 years old and she doesn't want to live with her mother anymore
There is no court order and I don't pay child support. There is no abuse going on that I know of. My daughter simply wants to stay in Texas living with me. I have no animosity or bad feelings towards my daughter's mother. We actually get a long quite well. I want to respect my daughters decision. I don't want to fight with her mother. What can her mother legally do if I don't send my daughter back to her?

I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited to Law.SE.

If you do take it to Law.SE be aware that they have a rule against providing legal advice. They can answer the general question "what can a parent legally do if they can't get access to their child in Texas?", but not anything specific to your circumstances.

We do not, and cannot provide legal guidance on this site.

In Texas, if there is no court order saying otherwise:

If one parent keeps a child away from the other parent when there is not a court order, there is no way to force visitation to happen. Without a court order, neither parent can file an enforcement action. An enforcement action cannot be used to enforce an informal agreement between the parents.

Basically you and the mother are expected to work together in the child's best interests. There is a strong presumption that this is going to involve the child spending time with both parents.

When there is no court order, there are no rules for visitation, and both parents have equal rights to the child. The law expects that the parents will work together to parent the child by agreement according to the child’s best interests.

If you don't send your daughter to visit her mother then this page outlines what she can do and the likely outcome (which would be a court order providing a standard list of visits):
Since your daughter is old enough to have a reasoned opinion on the matter, a court would likely take account of her preferences in making an order.

The second page applies to when there is suspected abuse, just clarifying.

@anongoodnurse Some of it does, but AIUI the Standard Possession Order is used when there are no concerns. A Supervised Possession Order would be used if there are safety concerns. But I'm not an expert in any way.
